# core data sqlite file is corrupted

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I'm working on an app that on logout I'm deleting the sqlite file and upon log in I'm creating a new one but after logging back in and while getting the data from the server I'm encountering a mystery issue that I could not fix since 2 weeks:

```
2013-04-29 07:05:09.107 APP[85958:1cd03] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZACTION, t0.ZDISPLAYNAME, t0.ZENTITYNAMELIST, t0.ZFIELDCONSULTANTID, t0.ZKEY, t0.ZLASTUPDATETIME, t0.ZMESSAGE, t0.ZPATH, t0.ZPERIODMONTH, t0.ZPERIODYEAR, t0.ZREQUESTDURATION, t0.ZREQUESTNAME, t0.ZREQUESTSTARTTIME, t0.ZSTATE, t0.ZSTOREID, t0.ZTERRITORYID, t0.ZUPDATEDURATION, t0.ZUPDATESTARTTIME FROM ZSYNCREQUESTENTITY t0 WHERE  t0.ZKEY = ?  LIMIT 1 
2013-04-29 07:05:09.107 APP[85958:1cd03] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = "TERRITORY_DATA" 
2013-04-29 07:05:09.108 APP[85958:1cd03] CoreData: annotation: Disconnecting from sqlite database due to an error. 
2013-04-29 07:05:09.166 APP[85958:1cd03] CoreData: error: (26) Fatal error.  The database at /Users/admin/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/C01FFF00-8530-4C8E-B954-AD9A70149972/Library/Application Support/APP/APP.sqlite is corrupted.  SQLite error code:26, 'file is encrypted or is not a database'
```

I'm using MagicalRecord third party to handle merging of context in background. I'm not sure if it can be the cause of the issue

any help would be appreciated ?

Thanks.

EDITED:

here is the stacktrace of 2 threads that might help to track the issue

```
thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x02228e52 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x02228e52 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
    frame #1: 0x0069d772 CoreData`_execute + 1634
    frame #2: 0x0069d011 CoreData`-[NSSQLiteConnection execute] + 2801
    frame #3: 0x006b15ce CoreData`-[NSSQLChannel selectRowsWithStatement:] + 94
    frame #4: 0x006ba28f CoreData`newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT + 1279
    frame #5: 0x006a56e3 CoreData`-[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 323
    frame #6: 0x006a4e07 CoreData`-[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 711
    frame #7: 0x006a48f4 CoreData`-[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 404
    frame #8: 0x006a3a6d CoreData`-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 2445
    frame #9: 0x006a19c9 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 569
    frame #10: 0x006f4276 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentObjectsForFetchRequest:inContext:error:] + 502
    frame #11: 0x0076e155 CoreData`__82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke_0 + 677
    frame #12: 0x006f4071 CoreData`internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 17
    frame #13: 0x03d9a014 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
    frame #14: 0x03d89d5f libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 58
    frame #15: 0x03d89aa3 libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_barrier_sync_f + 108
    frame #16: 0x006f403b CoreData`_perform + 187
    frame #17: 0x006f3e9e CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 238
    frame #18: 0x006a19c9 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 569
    frame #19: 0x006f4276 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentObjectsForFetchRequest:inContext:error:] + 502
    frame #20: 0x0076e155 CoreData`__82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke_0 + 677
    frame #21: 0x006f4071 CoreData`internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 17
    frame #22: 0x03d8b731 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 89
    frame #23: 0x03d9a014 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
    frame #24: 0x03d8a7d5 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 296
    frame #25: 0x03565af5 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1925
    frame #26: 0x03564f44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #27: 0x03564e1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #28: 0x02d6e7e3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 88
    frame #29: 0x02d6e668 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #30: 0x0117065c UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
    frame #31: 0x000030ad SubwayDA`main + 125 at main.m:12

thread #29: tid = 0x4103, 0x986d6c5e libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
        frame #0: 0x986d6c5e libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
        frame #1: 0x03d8bf08 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait + 16
        frame #2: 0x03d89b3a libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 149
        frame #3: 0x03d89a5c libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_barrier_sync_f + 37
        frame #4: 0x006f403b CoreData`_perform + 187
        frame #5: 0x006f3e9e CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 238
    frame #6: 0x006a19c9 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 569
    frame #7: 0x00236fbb APP`__67+[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord) MR_executeFetchRequest:inContext:]_block_invoke_0 + 251 at NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m:33
    frame #8: 0x006f3d3f CoreData`developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 95
    frame #9: 0x03d9a014 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
    frame #10: 0x03d89d5f libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 58
    frame #11: 0x03d89aa3 libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_barrier_sync_f + 108
    frame #12: 0x006f3cba CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 202
    frame #13: 0x00236d9d APP`+[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord) MR_executeFetchRequest:inContext:] + 285 at NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m:29
    frame #14: 0x002372ed APP`+[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord) MR_executeFetchRequestAndReturnFirstObject:inContext:] + 141 at NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m:53
    frame #15: 0x002351a6 APP`+[NSManagedObject(MagicalFinders) MR_findFirstWithPredicate:inContext:] + 150 at NSManagedObject+MagicalFinders.m:128
    frame #16: 0x002350d0 APP`+[NSManagedObject(MagicalFinders) MR_findFirstWithPredicate:] + 128 at NSManagedObject+MagicalFinders.m:121
    frame #17: 0x001f2a3d APP`-[SyncRequestOperation updateSyncRequestFromItem:] + 173 at SyncRequestOperation.m:148
    frame #18: 0x001f2c91 APP`-[SyncRequestOperation updateSyncRequestFromItemOnCurrentThread] + 97 at SyncRequestOperation.m:181
    frame #19: 0x001f4033 APP`-[SyncRequestOperation loadEntities] + 355 at SyncRequestOperation.m:292
    frame #20: 0x001f4f8a APP`-[SyncRequestOperation main] + 890 at SyncRequestOperation.m:385
    frame #21: 0x01c61d23 Foundation`-[__NSOperationInternal start] + 736
    frame #22: 0x01c61a34 Foundation`-[NSOperation start] + 79
    frame #23: 0x01cee301 Foundation`__block_global_6 + 150
    frame #24: 0x03d8853f libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    frame #25: 0x03d9a014 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
    frame #26: 0x03d8b2e8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 335
    frame #27: 0x03d8afcb libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread3 + 20
    frame #28: 0x9a1f0b24 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 346
```

Comment: The file is corrupt, that's about all anyone can say with the information you've included. If you add your code showing how you try to delete the store file, including steps taken before and after the actual delete call, it might be possible to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Make sure to not only delete the store file but also the journal file as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving the same error when trying to clear out my Core Data 'database'.

Christian's comment in your question resolved the issue for me. After I remove my NSPersistentStore, I then also clear our the documents directory. This deletes the sql journal file, which removed the error for me.

```
NSPersistentStore *store = [ad.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores lastObject];
NSError *error;
NSURL *storeURL = store.URL;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *storeCoordinator = ad.persistentStoreCoordinator;
[storeCoordinator removePersistentStore:store error:&error];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:storeURL.path error:&error];
[self deleteFilesInDocumentsDirectory];


- (void)deleteFilesInDocumentsDirectory
{
    NSString *folderPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSError *error = nil;
    for (NSString *file in [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderPath error:&error]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] error:&error];
    }
}
```

Comment: The journal files you need to delete are .sqlite-shm and .sqlite-wal. And they should be in the same directory as your .sqlite file, which may or may not be at the root Documents directory like shown above.